# Enterprise Architect: Command line generation of DDL for a package

Tags: command-line, ddl, enterprise-architect

I would like to include the generation of DDL from packages into our nightly builds, so that we don't have to check-in the generate schema (and the ORM classes we generate from the schema afterwards).

I cannot see any way to do this through the command line, without the Generate Package DDL UI. There's no info in the EA documentation [link](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/database_engineering/generateddlforapackage.html)

Has anyone found a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly doable using EA's API.

The so-called "EA Object Model" is available from inside EA (scripting) as well as from the .NET and Java APIs (while the "Add-In Model" is only available through .NET). Interaction with the EA repository is based on two classes, `Repository` and `Project`. So for the command line you'd need to write a program which

1. connects to the relevant EA repository -- `Repository::OpenFile`
2. retrieves the Project interface -- `Repository::GetProjectInterface`
3. retrieves the packages and elements -- `Repository::Get[Package/Element]By[ID/Guid]`
4. generates the DDL -- `Project::Generate[Package/Element]DDL`

In order to traverse a package/element structure, use the `Package::Packages` and `Package::Elements` collections (and possibly `Element::Elements`, but database models don't usually have elements inside other elements).

For future readers, please note that the `Project` class also includes similar methods to generate code, WSDL and XSD.

Relevant help file pages are under Automation and Scripting -- Enterprise Architect Object Model -- Reference (in EA 10.0.1007):

- Repository Package -- Repository Class
- Project Interface Package -- Project Class
- Repository Package -- Package Class
- Repository Package -- Element Class
- Repository Package -- Collection Class